# How to sort a vector to a txt file

Tags: sorting, assembly, arm

I'm using Armsim and I need to take some integers from a txt file and then I've to order and print them ordered in another txt file. How can I do? I mean, I managed to read the numbers, but I can't print them in order

Here's what I wrote:

```
.equ SWI_Open, 0x66        @open a file
.equ SWI_Close,0x68        @close a file
.equ SWI_PrChr,0x00        @ Write an ASCII char to Stdout
.equ SWI_PrStr, 0x69       @ Write a null-ending string 
.equ SWI_PrInt,0x6b        @ Write an Integer
.equ SWI_RdInt,0x6c        @ Read an Integer from a file
.equ Stdout,  1            @ Set output target to be Stdout
.equ SWI_Exit, 0x11        @ Stop execution

.data
i: .asciiz "7.2in.txt"
o: .asciiz "7.2o.txt"

.text
_main:
        ldr r0, =i
        mov r1, #0
        swi 0x66
        mov r2, r0
        ldr r0, =o
        mov r1, #1
        swi 0x66
        mov r1, r2
        bl copy
        swi 0x11

copy:
    mov r1, r0              
    mov r3, r2
    mov r0, r2
    swi 0x6c                
loop:
    mov r4, r0
    mov r0, r2
    swi 0x6c
    cmp r0, #00
    beq end
    cmp r4, r0
    ble no_scambio

    mov r2, r3
    mov r3, r1
    mov r1, r0
    mov r0, r3
    swi 0x6b
    mov r0, r1
    mov r1, r3
    mov r3, r2
    b loop

no_scambio:
    mov r2, r3
    mov r2, r1
    mov r1, r0
    mov r0, r2
    swi 0x6b
    mov r0, r1
    mov r1, r2
    mov r2, r3
    b loop

end:
    mov pc, lr
```

Comment: You can't sort a stream of numbers, at least I'm not aware of any algorithm capable to do that. AFAIK you will have to read the numbers into memory, and then apply some sorting algorithm over that memory structure, then you can convert the memory content into ASCII and write that into file as result.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on what kind of sorting program you can use? Since you are using syscalls can you use other non-syscalls programs within your OS?

Comment: i dont have particular restrictions. I used those syscalls only because i know only that way to open-read-write a file